# How to add a Maven repository other then 'central' in Azure Devops Artifacts feed?

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I want to use [com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc version 4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0)
in my Azure Devops Artifacts feed. It's located at [Clojars repo](https://clojars.org/repo/)). Is there a way to connect to this Clojars repo to my Feed in Azure Devops?

Comment: I want to avoid uploading this as an external JAR. But if I have to, do anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to connect to this Clojars repo to my Feed in Azure Devops?

I am afraid there is no such way to connect Clojars repo to the Feed in Azure Devops.

That because we could configure a custom upstream source for public repositories other than those listed above. But **custom upstream sources are only available for npm**.

Check the note on this thread: [Add public upstream sources to an existing feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#add-public-upstream-sources-to-an-existing-feed)

So, we need to publish this package to the Azure Devops Artifacts feed.

You could check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops#publish-an-artifact) for the details.